# Copy face from Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm a noob to this forum, but wanted to give it a try.

I'm currently learning Objective-C and Cocoa; trying to build my first iPhone app.

One thing I'm working on is allowing the user to cut his/her face from an image they have taken and paste it into another image.  (The idea is cut from one image and paste into another image with a spot for a face to go.)

How can this be done?  I am thinking I would allow the user to just touch and drag over their face, in the shape of a rectangle, and then allow them to copy.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "GIMME TEH CODEZ" is generally not considered to be a good question format. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm just getting into iOS development.  I was mainly just looking for some starting points; areas to focus on in regards to this topic.  I'm not looking for a free code handout, just some thoughtful ideas. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use Cocoa to make an iOS app. You must use Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, nevertheless your bit arrogant style of asking, here are some guidelines about how to start: generic obj-c/iOS development (start from hello world); UIImage class; camera API; image processing algorithms, face detection algorithms. Go on gradually and do not wish to resolve all problems at once. Write first an application that simple loads an arbitrary photo and shows it to the user. Then modify it that you can crop a specified rectangular area from the image and save it into the new file. Then write an app that switches on the camera that you can take an image and save it to the disk. Then unite what you wrote that you save only a cropped area of the captured image.

When you arrive to this point, you will know much more about software development image handling. AFTER THIS you can start looking for image processing algorithms. Start also here with something simple like a trivial blur filter or similar implemented by you. If you know already a bit of image processing, search for face detection algorithms on the net. It is even possible that you will find some ready framework that includes also these features, or at least you will understand the concepts. You can even come back here to stack overflow and ask for suggestions about a good face detection algorithms, however we still prefer if you have chosen already one and have some concrete issue with it.

Comment: This provides me somewhere to start.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There's no need to implement a face detection algorithm yourself; Core Image provides an API for that on iOS.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHosey for pointing this out. I was not aware of it.